# How to use ternary operator in query param?

Tags: angular

I have a anchor tag with query parameters in angular 2, I am trying to pass a query parameter in it as i have shown below.

```html
      <a  [routerLink]="['/inventory/clientpurchaseorder/add']"
 [queryParams]="{vendor_id:selectedVendor?selectedVendor.id:""}"
  class="btn btn-info">
```

I am trying to use ternary operator as i shown above. but i think its not the right way to do it. something is going wrong in what i have done, how i should use ternary operator here?

What is the exact form if i am using ternary operator in html side?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ternary operator is used like this :

```
<a
    [routerLink]="['/inventory/clientpurchaseorder/add']"
    [queryParams]="{vendor_id:selectedVendor ? selectedVendor.id : ''}"
    class="btn btn-info"
>
```

Comment: Sorry, typo, here you go !

Comment: Out of curiosity.. what's changed here? The double quotes to single quotes? If so, it's worth to mention that it was the problem :)

Comment: Yes, only that. Now that you mentioned it, I don't have to ! ;)

Comment: @trichetriche don't hide important info in comments; *explain* your answers.